# Delay in Kubernetes Job status update when running many jobs in parallel

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

I have a bit of a unique use-case where I want to run a large number (thousands to tens of thousands) of Kubernetes Jobs at once. Each job consists of a single container, Parallelism 1 and Completions 1, with no side-car or agent. My cluster has plenty of capacity for the resources I'm requesting.

My problem is that the Job status is not transitioning to Complete for a significant period of time when I run many jobs concurrently.

My application submits Jobs and has a watcher on the namespace - as soon as a Job's status transitions to 'succeeded 1', we delete the Job and send information back to the application. The application needs this to happen as soon as possible in order to define and submit subsequent Jobs.

I'm able to submit new Job requests as fast as I want, and Pod scheduling happens without delay, but beyond about one or two hundred concurrent Jobs I get significant delay between a Job's Pod completing and the Job's status updating to Complete. At only around 1,000 jobs in the cluster, it can easily take 5-10 minutes for a Job status to update.

This tells me there is some process in the Kubernetes Control Plane that needs more resources to process Pod completion events more rapidly, or a configuration option that enables it to process more tasks in parallel. However, my system monitoring tools have not yet been able to identify any Control Plane services that are maxing out their available resources while the cluster processes the backlog, and all other operations on the cluster appear to be normal.

My question is - where should I look for system resource or configuration bottlenecks? I don't know enough about Kubernetes to know exactly what components are responsible for updating a Job's status.

Comment: What is the k8s version and is it a standalone deployment or managed one (gke, eks,etc)?

Comment: Additionally it is needed to know what is the cluster configuration? How many master nodes/etcd instances you have? Can you share job manifest so it'll be possible to reproduce the issue?